# How to pass Discount details along with BasketXML?

Tags: java, opayo

I am integrating sagepay 3.0 in my System.

Where I want to pass Discounts along with BasketXML as suggested in [documentation](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/14206/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_050115.pdf?token=jwimtbXQc-MmWWdGJHNJZFeshXg2re_chVFqiebQ2wc) 48th page.

But there is no such method in Basket class to pass discounts.

I am using sagepay-api-1.2.2.0.jar library for my integration.

```
    Basket basket = new Basket();
    // ... set common params to basket
    // basket.setDiscounts(discounts); // not exists!

    BasketXmlFormatter xmlFormatter = new BasketXmlFormatter();
    String basketXml = xmlFormatter.toXml(iFormPayment, basket);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no such method to set Discounts in basket. We need to append XML string manually.

```
    String discountXML = "<discounts>";
    String discountTag = "<discount>"; // can be muliple
    discountTag += "<fixed>" + discountPrice + "</fixed>"; // REQUIRED
    discountTag += "<description>10% Discount Applied</description>";
    discountTag += "</discount>";
    discountXML += discountTag;
    discountXML += "</discounts>";

    BasketXmlFormatter xmlFormatter = new BasketXmlFormatter();
    String basketXml = xmlFormatter.toXml(iFormPayment, basket);
    basketXml = basketXml.replace("</basket>", discountXML + "</basket>");
```